# Php preg_replace - regular expression (remove tokens)

Tags: php, expression, preg-replace

I have content with tokens and want to strip all token which DOES NOT start with **test**. For example I have content:

```
$content = 'Hello [test:username]. What are you [token:name]';
$string = preg_replace('/\[test(.*)\]/', '', $content);
```

This work but replace with empty string all token which start with **test**. I want opposite which **does not start** with **test** and replace all another. How should I change regular expression. I want to get this result after preg_replace:

```
$content = 'Hello [test:username]. What are you';
```

Comment: Look at the regex docs, especially using `^` at the beginning of your pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
(?:\[test:[^]]+\])(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\[\w[^]]+\])
```

So your code looks like as

```
preg_replace('/(?:\[test:[^]]+\])(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:\[\w[^]]+\])/', '', $content);
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\[test:[^]]+\]) // Will capture a group of tokens that have same 
                      pattern like as [test:...]

(*SKIP)(*F)        // This is supported by PCRE to skip the above captured group 

|(?:\[\w[^]]+\])   // This'll capture rest of the group that doesn't 
                     contains pattern like as [test:...]
```

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad it helped you. @user3421014 I've also added an explanation too for future users